# python TypeError: string indices must be integers json

Tags: python, json

Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong ?I am Getting this error.. 
went through the earlier post of similar error. couldn't able to understand..

```
import json
import re
import requests
import subprocess
res = requests.get('https://api.tempura1.com/api/1.0/recipes', auth=('12345','123'), headers={'App-Key': 'some key'})
data = res.text
extracted_recipes = []
for recipe in data['recipes']:
  extracted_recipes.append({
            'name': recipe['name'],
            'status': recipe['status']
        })
  print extracted_recipes
```

**TypeError: string indices must be integers**

**data contains the below**

```
{
    "recipes": {
        "47635": {
            "name": "Desitnation Search",
            "status": "SUCCESSFUL",
            "kitchen": "eu",
            "active": "YES",
            "created_at": 1501672231,
            "interval": 5,
            "use_legacy_notifications": false
        },
        "65568": {
            "name": "Validation",
            "status": "SUCCESSFUL",
            "kitchen": "us-west",
            "active": "YES",
            "created_at": 1522583593,
            "interval": 5,
            "use_legacy_notifications": false
        },
        "47437": {
            "name": "Gateday",
            "status": "SUCCESSFUL",
            "kitchen": "us-west",
            "active": "YES",
            "created_at": 1501411588,
            "interval": 10,
            "use_legacy_notifications": false
        }
    },
    "counts": {
        "total": 3,
        "limited": 3,
        "filtered": 3
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `data = res.text` which is telling me that `data` is now a string. Should you be doing `data = json.loads(res.text)`?

Comment: @quamrana: or just `res.json()`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: I didn't know that. Does requests return a `json` object as well?

Comment: Please update the *question* with the full traceback. Even with the above comment it is not clear which is `line 9`.

Comment: @quamrana there's no such thing as a "json object" in Python. json is a text format, which is then parsed into native python types (dicts, lists, ints, floats, strings, etc). Both `json.loads(res.text)` or `res.json()` will return the same thing, in this case a dict of dicts.

Comment: @quamrana 

import json
import re
import requests
res = requests.get('https://api.tempura1.com/api/1.0/recipes', auth=('12345','123'), headers={'App-Key': 'bc9y1dmq8xsm3tykuasdd4o7ptz7'})
data = res.json()
extracted_recipes = []
for recipe in data['recipes']:
  extracted_recipes.append({
            'name': recipe['name'],
            'status': recipe['status']
        })

  print extracted_recipes

Comment: For this I am getting 

Traceback (most recent call last): File "python", line 9, in <module> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Sorry, my bad. I think I must have meant that requests calls `loads` from the `json` library.

Comment: Please update the **question** with the full traceback. Are you able to use the `edit` button below your question? (I think some users don't have this).

Comment: @quamrana it's actually a bit more involved that just calling `json.loads()` (it's OSS so you can read the source by yourself) but basically yes.

Answer (score 1):

You are not converting the text to json. Try

```
data = json.loads(res.text)
```

or

```
data = res.json()
```

Apart from that, you probably need to change the for loop to loop over the values instead of the keys. Change it to something the following

```
for recipe in data['recipes'].values()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @Lokesh. You probably need to change `for recipe in data['recipes']:` to `for recipe in data['recipes'].values():`

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code, which you could have found out by yourself by doing a very minimal amount of debugging.

The first problem is that you don't parse the response contents from json to a native Python object. Here:

```
data = res.text
```

`data` is a string (json formatted, but still a string). You need to parse it to turn it into it's python representation (in this case a dict). You can do it using the stdlib's `json.loads()` (general solution) or, since you're using python-requests, just by calling the `Response.json()` method:

```
data = res.json()
```

Then you have this:

```
for recipe in data['recipes']:
    # ...
```

Now that we have turned `data` into a proper `dict`, we can access the `data['recipes']` subdict, *but* iterating directly over a `dict` actually iterates over the keys, not the values, so in your above `for` loop `recipe` will be a string ( "47635", "65568" etc). If you want to iterate over the values, you have to ask for it explicitly:

```
for recipe in data['recipes'].values():
    # now `recipe` is the dict you expected
```